# About Magnetic Susceptibility

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, magnetic-fields

I am working on the measurements of magnetic susceptibility of various materials using electromagnetic induction phenomenon. I have made a solenoid with primary and secondary windings coils. How do I check it whether it works or not?

Comment: Why are you giving "hints" to potential answerers? If you have more information than you're putting down, now is the time to explain what you do and do not know about your situation.

Comment: This question is unclear. What do you want to check?

Comment: Emilio Pisanty, I have edited. Now you are happy ?

Comment: Yashas Samaga, I want to check whether the solenoid I have made gives me "Zero" magnetic effect or not! Because i have made the secondary and primary coil windings opposite to each other to get zero magentic effect.
(Sorry for my poor english, I am an undergraduate student)

Comment: *How do I check it whether it works or not?* Aside from turning it on and trying it on known samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a multimeter to test the solenoid. Connect the two ends of the solenoid to a multimeter and then measure the resistance. The solenoid should have specs about the resistance, with which you can compare your multimeter readings

Comment: Don't you want to measure the inductance, rather than the resistance?

Comment: I want to check whether the solenoid I have made gives me "Zero" magnetic effect or not! Because i have made the secondary and primary coil windings opposite to each other to get zero magentic effect. (Sorry for my poor english, I am an undergraduate student)